# Firestore: Best way to check if subcollection is exist?

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

````
├── users ----------------------------------------------- collection
│   ├── u1 ---------------------------------------------- document
│   │   ├── displayName: "John Smith"
│   │   ├── email: "public"
│   │   ├── photoURL: "xxx.png"
│   │   │
│   |   └── chatChannels -------------------------------- subcollection
│   |       └── c1
|   |            ├── channelId: "c1"
|   |            ├── joinedAt : 12/12/2017
│   │   ```
|   
├── converstations -------------------------------------- collection
│   ├── c1  --------------------------------------------- document  
│   |   ├── channelName: "Channel 1"
│   |   ├── channelType: "public"
│   |   ├── channelIcon: "channel.png"
│   |   │   
│   |   ├── members ------------------------------------- subcollection
│   |   |    ├── u1
│   |   |    |   ├── userId: "u1"
|   |   |    |    
|   |   |    
|   |   ├── messages ------------------------------------ subcollection
│   |        ├── m1
│   |            ├── from: "u1"
|   |            ├── message: "hello"
|   |            ├── timestamp: 12/12/2017 00:09 PM
````

This is a chatting app structure what I am building with `firestore`. There is only a problem to remove subcollections from a document.

1. remove a document.
2. if subcollections exist, remove them.

For example, if I remove `"Channel 1"`, it also needs to remove all subcollections(`members` and `messages`).

*let's say I don't know their names, because I just want to make a
    common provider on entire project. In other case, I can make it manually using [batch operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)*

Comment: did you figure something out? I need to do something very similar, where I want to delete a collection and check if this collection has other subcollections so that I can use recursion and delete everything.

Comment: I couldn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive delete is not built into the client libraries. If you really need to recursively delete a document and all it's sub-collections you can use the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#delete_data) or the [Firebase cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#cloud_firestore_commands).